# How to restrict getting field (e.g. password) in symfony 4?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

Using Symfony 4. 
I need to get Trader and Wallet records from database.
Using query:

```
$this->_em->getRepository('App:Trader')->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t as trader', 'w as wallet')
        ->leftJoin('App:Wallet', 'w', Join::WITH, "w.trader=t.id");
```

As result I get all fields of trader and wallet entities as well.
I don't want to show trader's `password`.

How to get the same result but without `password` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to explicitly specify the fields you want (and use the `partial` keyword if you want to get it as an entity object).

```
$fields = 'partial t.{id, name}, partial w.{id, balance}'; // guessing the columns

$this->_em->getRepository('App:Trader')->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->select($fields)
    ->leftJoin('App:Wallet', 'w', Join::WITH, "w.trader=t.id");
```

[Here's](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax) the documentation regarding the `partial` keyword.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.